# Cant use multiple displays

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I've recently bought a new PC

XServer :

```
Version: 1:7.7+16ubuntu3
```

Video card:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK104 [GeForce GTX 760 OEM]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I've tried both noveau drivers and nvidea proprietary. 
I can only use one monitor:

[image: arandr view]

I'm using ubuntu 17.04

I've checked if my monitors work in windows and they worked out of the box, so it's not a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turn's out this does not occours when using Noveau drivers, so if you're experiencing something similar, try:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

And under `Additional Drivers` tab pick `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`.

Leaving this open for answers in case someone comes up with a solution for proprietary drivers.